# Can i have multiple login methods for WSO2 IS/AM?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Currently i am using SSO(single sign on) based user authentication from a primary user store - LDAP. I want to shift to tenant-based authentication keeping my LDAP authentication active. Can these both work together? I did not find any documentation from WSO2 regarding this.

Comment: Do you mean to have multiple sessions in the same browser for different tenants?

Comment: No sir, I want to make authorization via 2 methods: that is from Primary user store as well as tenant based.

Answer (score 1):

Although you have moved to a tenant mode. You can still create users in the primary user store that you are currently using in the super tenant. When using single sign on you will have to specify the tenant domain to identify the user.

example: 
Let's say you have created a tenant named abc.com and a user named kim under that tenant but in the primary user store. When logging in you will have to use the user name as.

username: kim@abc.com

Also, your service provider application should provide the tenant domain as a query parameter in the request.

Comment: Currently i have configured LDAP as my primary user store. I can login with my username & passwd. In addition to this, i want tenant based login. Is it mandatory to assign LDAP under one of my tenants? Can these 2 methods be set up independently?

Comment: what do you mean by tenant based login? If it is just separating your users based on tenant domain yes it is possible. The LDAP will be the primary user store across all tenants. But you can add users specifying their tenant domain to ldap. When logging also you can use the tenant domain as i mentioned in the answer. Are you refering to something like second factor authentication based on the tenant domain?

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the answer by @Buddima, if you want users from different tenant to login to your application you need to enable [SaaS Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJgPJ.png) option in the respective Service Provider. **Note**: if you didn't enable this option you cannot use the one tenant users to log in to other tenant applications.

To have more complex multiple login methods, it is better to use adaptive scripts. There we can have more conditions based on tenants and user stores. To learn more, follow the doc https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/configuring-tenant-based-adaptive-authentication/